# multiline edit box: why do I missed character?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am writing a program to display characters from rs232 using a thread with a windows GUI. The received string is appended to the end of the textbox in the thread. I found that the receiving is correct, but the display always misses quite a lot of the characters. 
Below is the thread which receives and display the received string on the edit box.

```
UINT CTestserialDlg::SerialRecv(LPVOID pParam)
{
    int *p=(int*)pParam;
    AsyncSerialPort *s=(AsyncSerialPort*)p[0];
    CTestserialDlg *pView=(CTestserialDlg*)p[1];
    char buf[1024];
    char str[1024];
    int count=0;
    while(1)
    {
        s->WaitForRecv();
        Sleep(10);
        int nbytes_recvd=s->recv_nowait(buf);
        buf[nbytes_recvd]=0;
        count+=nbytes_recvd;

        TRACE("Bytes recvd: %d/%d\n",nbytes_recvd,count);
        //update the GUI area for the message
        //first convert to hex string
        if(!nbytes_recvd) //there is a chance that get zero bytes
            continue;
        if(pView->HexOut)
        {
            str[0]=0;
            for(int i=0;i<nbytes_recvd;i++)
                sprintf(str+i*3,"%02x ",buf[i]&0xff);
            str[i*3]=0x0d;
            str[i*3+1]=0x0a;
            str[i*3+2]=0;
            //pView->m_list_text.AddString(str);
            //pView->m_edit_text.SetWindowText(str);
            int nlen=pView->m_edit_text.GetWindowTextLength();
            pView->m_edit_text.SetSel(nlen,nlen);
            pView->m_edit_text.ReplaceSel(str);

        }
        else
        {
            //strcpy(buf, "aaa\r\nbbb");
            //pView->m_list_text.AddString(buf);
            //int line=pView->m_edit_text.GetLineCount();
            int nlen=pView->m_edit_text.GetWindowTextLength();
            pView->m_edit_text.SetSel(nlen,nlen);
            pView->m_edit_text.ReplaceSel(buf);
            //pView->m_edit_text.LineScroll(line);
            //pView->m_edit_text.SetWindowText(buf);
            TRACE("%s",buf);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I send a cpp file with 878 characters and the program results:

The debug TRACE output:
*

```
#include "asyncserialport.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    if(argc!=3 && argc!=4)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s port txtfile baudrate(default=9600)",argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    int portnum=atoi(argv[1]);
    int baud=9600;
    if(argc==4)
        baud=atoi(argv[3]);
    AsyncSerialPort s;
    if(!s.init(portnum,baud,8,0,0,0,1024,1024))
    {
        printf("serial port %d open error\n",portnum);
        exit(-1);
    }
    char line[256];
    FILE* fp=fopen(argv[2],"r");
    int count=0;
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        fgets(line,256,fp);
        //append \r\n it only has new line but no carriage return 
        int len=strlen(line);
        if(line[len-1]=='\n')
        {
            line[len-1]=0x0d;
            line[len]=0x0a;
            line[len+1]=0;
        }
        printf("%s",line);
        s.send_wait(line,strlen(line),1000);
        count+=strlen(line);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("\n%d bytes transmitted\n",count);
    s.close();
}
```

Bytes recvd: 0/878

The edit textbox display as:

```
#include "asyncserialport.h"
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc,char **argv)
    {
        if(argc!=3 && argc!=4)
        {
            printf("Usage: %s port txtfile baudrate(default=9600)",argv[0]);
            exit(0);
        }
        int portnum=atoi(argv[1]);
        int baud=9600;
        if(argc==4)
            baud=atoi(argv[3]);
        AsyncSeria
```

A lot of characters are missing. The recv actually looped 4 times, and the 3rd time string are not displayed and totally lost in the edit box.
I am wondering if the three function GetWindowTextLength, SetSel, ReplaceSel work properly when it runs too fast? (baudrate at 115200 and send/recv the file is very fast)
Anyone can give me some hints on this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have got the answer. It is not due to the code, but due to the editbox. I have modified the editbox property with HScroll and AutoHscroll and everything now seems normal.